# Function on a variable declaration

Tags: c

I'm reading the C Programming Language (chapter 5), and I'm confused by this example:

```
int n, array[SIZE], getint(int *);
```

Why is this function call in here like that? Is this just some tricky example and invalid code?

Comment: What kinda book it is and in which context this is mentioned? If it is given as a suggestion on how to actually write code, through the book away and never pick it up.

Comment: @SergeyA it is this book:https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-3H1iJSfZVCs/Wcd5CW-CXVI/AAAAAAAAAjQ/dFdRebqpksQfsiIAHVIfQukTpLKdYi2cgCLcBGAs/s320/_20170924_111559.JPG

Comment: @Goxm OK, Famous K&R book. Is it super dated now, but you should not throw it away. Just be mindful that it describes language was it was 30 years ago.

Comment: What should I read for modern C programming?

Comment: I think K&R is a fine book to start out with. It's somewhat dated but not as impossibly dated as other commenters seem to imply. Sure, the second edition is 30 years old, but the C language has changed remarkably little in that time. Additionally, while I and many others prefer to declare only one variable per line, declaring multiple variables is both a totally valid use of the language, and a style that you *will* encounter when reading code in the wild -- and thus, it's good for a book that introduces you to the language to describe such things.

Comment: @Motheus [The Definitive C Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/q/562303/3342206)

Comment: Would you recognize it if equivalently if it said `int getint(int *), n, array[SIZE];` ? It's clearly a function defn not a call, since `getint(int *)` can't be passing an actual arg.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's not calling the function; it's declaring its prototype.
It's equivalent to:

```
int n;
int array[SIZE];
int getint(int*);
```

Comment: That was going to be my guess. Why would you do it like that though? Is the book just trying to show shorthand?

Comment: Who is this book by?

Comment: @Chipster The sort of code style that's favored has changed over the years.  Back then, shorter code was considered more readable, since you can fit more on the screen.  These days, people tend to prefer more code, but with lines that are individually more clear.  (I tend to be in the camp that favors shorter code, but even I would write this one out on three lines.)

Comment: @ııı Kernighan and Ritchie (the latter being the creator of C). The second edition is considered the canonical text on the language, although it's out of date now. (and will remain so, since Ritchie's dead.)

Comment: @Ray Which also made sense back in the days. Monitors could not show many rows on one screen.

Comment: @Ray Interesting. I didn't realize you could do that, although it makes sense now that I think about it. I personally would do 2 lines. 1 for n and array (those I don't mind together as much) and 1 for the prototype.

Comment: K&R style C is a nightmare I'm glad we've woken up from.

Comment: @Broman There's still a case to be made for compact code even now. The more code on the screen, the easier it is to see the big picture. Bigger monitors just mean we can see even *more* of the program at once. The algorithms are the hard parts to understand; fitting more on screen helps with that more than it hurts line-level readability. And a lot of the compact K&Risms only seem hard to read today because people aren't used to them. If you're fluent in both the language and the idioms, you can just glance at this sort of code and understand it as easily as you would `i = j + 1`.

Comment: @Chipster: Books, PowerPoint slides, and similar media have limited space, so they tend to use a more dense and compact coding style to fit more code on the page.  As far as the compiler is concerned, `getint(int *)` is just another declarator like `n` and `array[SIZE]`.  Outside of preprocessor directives, C doesn't care about newlines (or whitespace in general) except to separate tokens.  You could theoretically write all your non-preprocessor code on a single source line.  Not that you'd *do* that, but you could.

Comment: @JohnBode You could theoretically write all your non-preprocessor code as a [single](https://www.ioccc.org/1988/phillipps.c) [statement](https://www.ioccc.org/1988/phillipps.hint). You *really* shouldn't do that, though.

Comment: @Ray I agree that's a bad idea, but it'd be fun to try writing all your code as a single statement.

Comment: LOL guys it is funny we complain about "this" and "that" and what we take for granted. Take a look at some FreeBSD code that was written before ANSI standard. Back then you could not declare variables anywhere but at the beginning of function.

Comment: @Gox what are you referring to?! The *"Ansi C"*, i.e. ISO C90 only allowed declarations at the beginning of each *block/compound statement*; and this was the same as in K&R 1st ed. from 1978!

Comment: @AnttiHaapala???? So when did they allow variable declaration in the middle of the bock? K&R ANSI C (2nd edition) uses it all the time.

Comment: @Gox that was C99.

Comment: @Gox it doesn't. 2nd ed 4.9.: *"Declarations of variables (including initializations) may follow the left
brace that introduces any compound statement, not just the one that begins a
function."*

Comment: The second edition of the book used C89, and the first edition did not have prototypes.  As others have mentioned, you wouldn’t see this kind of definition today outside an obfuscated C contest.

Comment: @Davislor actually even the second ed *predates* the final standard, having been published in January 1988

Answer (score 3):

Since the statement began with a type specifier, namely int, then it suggests declaration. Thus what follows is a bunch of comma separated list of identifiers.

`n` being a single int variable.

`array` being an array of int.

`getint` being a function that returns an int and has one parameter that is an int pointer. It is unnamed and that is not important because this is a function declaration/prototype.